# LINQ to XML how do I get child element value with multiple namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml document here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf=8"?>
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>NugetName</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>company</authors>
    <owners>company</owners>
  </metadata>
  <files>
  ...
  </files>
</package>
```

I'm trying to get the value of "id".  I'm currently using XDocument and i've tried several different ways to go about this.

I thought for certain I could use the following:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
XNamespace xns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd";
XElement el = xmlDoc.Element(xns + "metadata");
XElement id = el.Element(xns + "id");
string idValue = id.Value;
Console.WriteLine(idValue);
```

However, I get Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I'm not sure how Element can be null. Do I need to declare project namespace too? I've tried that and I still get the Object reference error.  Could someone point out the novice mistake I've made?

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint on the xmlDoc variable and trace it through to see whether or not the XML file has been correctly loaded? I cant see where the file parameter has been initialised so its hard to know if the doc itself is null

Comment: Trying to figure out what's wrong with my debugger but in the mean time i put the xml document into a string literal and passed it using XDocument.Parse like this; `XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);` I get the same error.

Comment: Sounds like your document is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your root element also has namespace you select root element using namespace and using that reference you can reference metadata element. Simplest fix would be replace following line

```
XElement el = xmlDoc.Element(xns + "metadata");
```

with

```
XElement el = xmlDoc.Root.Element(xns + "metadata");
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Now I need to figure out if there's a way to dynamically get the namespace because it could change based on the nuspec i feed it.